# How to upload very large file to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a postgres backup about 100GB and want to load it to S3 in EU Frankfurt and restore it in cloud database.

I have no access to AWS Import/Export service on Ubuntu laptop

Strategies I have tried

1. management console upload, at least 2 weeks needed
2. bucket explore multi-upload, task failed due to Java memory error every time
3. SDK multi-upload (boto, boto3, Java SDK), do not show the progress bar. I cannot estimate how long it needs
4. other Windows explore, do not have Linux version

What is the fastest way to load this into S3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the AWS CLI (https://aws.amazon.com/de/cli/).

```
aws s3 cp /PATH_TO_BACKUP/BACKUP_FILE s3://BUCKETNAME
```

Comment: what if the connection is lost in between uploading  the large files say 50 GB file. Do, we need to re-upload the whole file again

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) tool:

`mc cp backup.zip s3/bucketname`